# REQUEST_URI contains favicon.ico path in php $_SERVER why

Tags: php

Variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains `favicon.ico` file path in home page. Why?

Comment: What is your favicon.ico url?

Comment: Can you show the full info please? ie. a full exact copy of what you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

Implementing SEO friendly URLs, one have always be aware that it acts like 404 handler and thus php router will be invoked on any **non-existing** URL, including favicon.ico (if it's absent).
So, one have to foresee such a possibility, and issue regular 404 response if none of application urls were recognized.

Comment: Well, that, or use the `-f` flag to catch those requests before they are passed on to the PHP interpreter (if using Apache's RewriteModule)